# c# Quickbooks query customer COMException was caught

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I'm new in integrating Quickbooks to c# and I'm having and error in BeginSession

Here is my code

```
bool sessionBegun = false;
            bool connectionOpen = false;
            QBSessionManager sessionManager = null;

            try
            {
                //Create the session Manager object
                sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();

                //Create the message set request object to hold our request
                IMsgSetRequest requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 10, 0);
                requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue;

                BuildCustomerAddRq(requestMsgSet);

                //Connect to QuickBooks and begin a session
                sessionManager.OpenConnection("", "Sample Code from OSR");
                connectionOpen = true;
                sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);
                sessionBegun = true;

                //Send the request and get the response from QuickBooks
                IMsgSetResponse responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet);

                //End the session and close the connection to QuickBooks
                sessionManager.EndSession();
                sessionBegun = false;
                sessionManager.CloseConnection();
                connectionOpen = false;

                WalkCustomerAddRs(responseMsgSet);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error");
                if (sessionBegun)
                {
                    sessionManager.EndSession();
                }
                if (connectionOpen)
                {
                    sessionManager.CloseConnection();
                }
            }
```

btw I just copy this code in this link [enter link description here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1568/c-net-application-with-quickbooks-desktop-edition.aspx)

and here is my error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you need to pass the name of the file into the BeginSession call.